# What is wrong with this rough PHP verification method?

Tags: php, verification

So, this is my code:

```
$login_user_name = $_POST['login-user-name'];
//salt is declared earlier
$login_user_pword = super_encrypt($_POST['login-user-pword'], $login_salt);     

$login_veri_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zebra_users WHERE username='".$login_user_name."'");

$login_veri_numrows = mysql_num_rows($login_veri_query);

if ($login_veri_numrows != 0) {
    while ($value = mysql_fetch_array($login_veri_query)) {
        if ($value['password'] == $login_user_pword) {
            $login_error .= '<p class="success">Logged in Successfully!</p><br/>';
            $main_error .= '<p class="success">Logged in Successfully!</p><br/>';
            $login_good = true;
            $login_error .= '<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- window.location = "main.php" //--> </script>';
        } else {
            $login_error .= '<p class="warning">Incorrect password, try again.</p><br>';
        }
    }
}
}
```

and if there were a user with the username of 'user' and password of 'pword', and those credentials were entered into the form, the "verification" method would claim the password was incorrect.

What's wrong here?

Also, I know this isn't really a good log-in style, but I'm using this as a placeholder, until I use cookies, which I don'

Comment: Simplify and isolate the issue... don't post your code file.

Comment: `super_encrypt`? Really? Just use SHA-1 and AES like the rest of us.

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated and present a security risk. Replace with PDO (http://php.net/PDO)

Comment: @Nile fixed. Patashu super_encrypt contains both those, and some more, I use it in several places though, so I wanted to just make it a function. Cfreak I'm using a slightly older model of PHP, where mysql_* functions aren't deprecated; I'll look into that though.

Comment: I hope it's not hashing a hash

Comment: @Zbee If it contains SHA-1 then it isn't encryption. Also, mysql_* is not a version-specific thing.

Comment: it's impossible to be logged in without cookies.

Comment: @Scuzzy Any particular reason why? Waleed Khan, I know, but I didn't when I named it; Oh, well, it works atm. Marshall House, Oh ... Well, this changes everything, thanks.

Comment: @Zbee A hash has a specific length (eg MD5 is 32 characters) and comprised of hexadecimal values (0-9 A-F), when you hash something of known length and alphabet size, you're greatly reducing it's effectiveness against brute force cracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it's susceptible to sql injection because you're not escaping the username.

Second of all you should be sending the hashed password to the database and it should be returning any user who's username and password hash match.  That way someone can't force the database to send the password hash simply by inputting the wrong password.

Third, what happens if no rows were returned from the database?  The actions for a failed password should be the same as the actions for a failed username.

Fourth you should have been using === to compare the password (though you shouldn't be using this method at all).  You wouldn't want an empty password to match FALSE or something similar.  Plus it just saves resources.